# How can I find what part of my code is throwing a runtime error in Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift and Xcode, as well as programming in general, and I have been following a tutorial to learn more. But, after getting a ways into the tutorial, my app throws a runtime error of 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping Optional value'. I know this means that I have an optional value that the compiler found nil in when I called it, but I have no idea how to find which of my optionals caused the error. If anyone could point me to how to find the optional, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Go to the breakpoint navigator.  Add an exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

When your app crashes, XCode typically highlights the line where it crashed and found nil.  Look at that line and trace is to see why it is nil.  Either initialize it with a value or make sure to check for nil values before performing any logic.